# I need code to make Wordpress displaying 5 columns of posts

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Could a WordPress guru please explain what php code I would need to get wordpress to display posts in a 5 column grid, with posts sorted automatically?

Comment: This is no wordpress support site here. Please ask in the forum over at wordpress.org. Please bear in mind that this site is for solving specific questions related to programming. It is not for answering questions of a non-specific nature. You are also strongly advised to show the code for your attempts to solve the problem you're having. The community tends to frown on people who don't demonstrate that they've tried to solve a problem before asking for help.

Comment: To keep it in the family, there's also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks ..  I didn't realise there was now a wordpress board. Cheers Deceze

Answer (score 3):

Did you read http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

This is your basic page skeleton:

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

In **Administration** > **Settings** > **Reading** you set how many post WordPress will show.

Here's a link about grid design. Lots of web resources: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/04/14/designing-with-grid-based-approach/

I would like to highlight the following points:

- No one design grid system is appropriate for all Web pages. Your first step is to establish a basic layout grid. With this graphic “backbone” you can determine how the major blocks of type and illustrations will regularly occur in your pages and set the placement and style guidelines for major screen titles, subtitles, and navigation links or buttons.
- “Well designed grid systems can make your designs not only more
  beautiful and legible, but more usable.”